# MySQL Select/Join Multiple Row in User Meta Table

Tags: mysql, join, meta

I have a table called `user_meta` and it contains data like:

```
---------------------------
| user_id | field | value |
---------------------------
|    1    |   1   | Green  |
|    1    |   2   | Square |
|    1    |   3   | Big    |
|    2    |   1   | Red    |
|    2    |   2   | Square |
|    2    |   3   | Small  |
----------------------------
```

The `field` column is the number of a form field in the user's profile. The `value` column is the value the user submitted via the form.

How do I write a MySQL query that returns all users who have 'green big squares'?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will return the result that you want. This uses a `WHERE` clause to return all records that have the values that you want, then you count the distinct values to make sure there are only 3:

```
select user_id
from user_meta
where value in ('Green', 'Square', 'Big')
group by user_id
having count(distinct value) = 3
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f1ddf/4)

Comment: This way seems to be a bit more efficient. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Using a subquery would work if you're stuck with that schema.  It's not going to be very fast though.

```
select userid 
from user_meta
where user_id in (
    select user_id from user_meta 
    where (field = 1 and value = 'Green')
)
and user_id in (
    select user_id from user_meta 
    where (field = 2 and value = 'Square')
)
and user_id in (
    select user_id from user_meta 
    where (field = 3 and value = 'Big')
)
```

Answer (score 1):

`SELECT user_id
FROM user_meta user_meta1
JOIN user_meta user_meta2 ON user_meta1.UserID = user_meta2.UserID
JOIN user_meta user_meta3 ON user_meta2.UserID = user_meta3.UserID
WHERE user_meta1.value = 'Green' AND user_meta2.value='Square' AND user_meta3.value='big'`